# Mock and inject ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a class `Foo` that has multiple dependencies to `ObservableObject`. For testing purposes I want to create a mocked version of those objects but I cannot see a way to do so and then inject those into `Foo`.

- I can't create another protocol that my `ObservableObject` implements because the `ObservableObject` protocol has self or associated type requirements and can't be used as a type declared and
- I cannot subclass the `ObservableObject` since it has `@Published` property wrapped members that cannot be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the only way I see is to write a mock subscriber that is subscribing to the `ObservableObject`:

```
final class SomeState: ObservableObject {
  @Published var someValue: String?
}
```

If the `ObservableObject` looks like this you could implement the mock subscriber (I call them `Watcher`) like this:

```
final class SomeStateWatcher {
  let someState: SomeState

  var didSetSomeValue: Bool = false
  var lastSomeValue: String?

  private var someValueSubscriber: AnyCancellable?

  init(someState: SomeState) {
    self.someState = someState

    self.someValueSubscriber = self.someState.$someValue
      .sink(receiveValue: { value in 
        self.didSetSomeValue = true
        self.lastSomeValue = value
      })
  }
}

func testDoStuffThatChangesTheLocalSomeStateProperty() {
  someImplementation.doStuffThatChangesTheLocalSomeStateProperty(with: "Fourty2")

  XCTAssertTrue(someStateWatcher.didSetSomeValue, "It should have published someValue")
  XCTAssertEqual(someStateWatcher.lastSomeValue, "Fourty2", "It should have published the correct value)
}
```